# Is there any other way to send transaction bundle to miners besides Flashbot?

Tags: etherscan, flashbots, mev, mev-searcher

I'm studying flash bot recently, and I found by chance that the first few transactions of this block(https://etherscan.io/txs?block=16655452&ps=100&p=2) seemed to be a flash bot bundle (because the gas price of the last transaction was much higher than the average value, indicating that the bundle sender gave the miners a very high reward to enable the bundle to be executed).
[image]
However, I didn't find any information about this bundle on https://flashbots-explorer.marto.lol/ (flashbot explorer), because the result returned by the webpage shows that there is no flash bot bundle on this block.
[image]

How to judge whether this is a flash bot bundle? If not, could it be something similar to the flashbot bundle? How does its sender build and send it?

Answer (score 0):

The project you have mentioned https://flashbots-explorer.marto.lol/ only explores blocks produced by Flashbots based on API it uses in code https://github.com/martriay/flashbots-explorer/blob/main/lib/api.ts. But there are many different block builders out there.

If we take a look on [the specific block you used in your example](https://etherscan.io/txs?block=16655452&ps=100&p=2), the fee recipient was `builder0x69`.
[image]